# how to open 2 named pipes on same machine?

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to run two instance of my program on my machine.
Each instance needs localhost named pipe:

```
_host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ManagementConsole),
            new Uri[]
            {
                new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")
            });

_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IManagementConsole),
     new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
     "PipeManagementConsole");

_host.Open();
```

In another instance of my program I use `PipeManagementConsole2`

So clients supposed to used `net.pipe://localhost/PipeManagementConsole` and `net.pipe://localhost/PipeManagementConsole2`.

However Windows doesn't allow second instance of my program to run, it claims that `net.pipe://localhost` is already in use (and it is), how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Multiple Services Over net.pipe in WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749756/running-multiple-services-over-net-pipe-in-wcf): you have to specify different URI's.

Comment: @CodeCaster but my URIs are different `net.pipe://localhost/PipeManagementConsole` and `net.pipe://localhost/PipeManagementConsole2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

different address should be specified when creating ServiceHost, not when calling AddServiceEndpoint.

This code works fine:

```
_host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ManagementConsole),
                            new Uri[]
                            {
                                new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/2")
                            });

_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IManagementConsole),
    new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
    "PipeManagementConsole");

_host.Open();
```

Clients should use `"net.pipe://localhost/2/PipeManagementConsole"`

But this code doesn't work:

```
_host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ManagementConsole),
                        new Uri[]
                        {
                            new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")
                        });

_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IManagementConsole),
    new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
    "PipeManagementConsole2");

_host.Open();
```

if `net.pipe://localhost/PipeManagementConsole` is already in use

I don't know why `net.pipe://localhost/2/PipeManagementConsole` is better than `net.pipe://localhost/PipeManagementConsole2`

Answer (score 5):

you can't

[image]